# Align bar graph with error bars in groups on Y-axis

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, bar-chart

Am trying to align this in group of 3's but a bar in the `AAAAAAAA` group keeps going off alignment.

Note: I have checked ["grouped bar chart with pgfplots"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/152143/grouped-bar-chart-with-pgfplots) , ["Bar graph with groups(inner group bars next to each other) and whitespace between groups including error bars [duplicate]"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/167804/bar-graph-with-groupsinner-group-bars-next-to-each-other-and-whitespace-betwee) and  ["How can i create bar plot groups of different sizes in pgfplots?"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43832/how-can-i-create-bar-plot-groups-of-different-sizes-in-pgfplots) and they don't answer my question - our data input format is different.

MWE:

[image: A labels]

```
\definecolor{bblue}{HTML}{82B1FF}
\definecolor{rred}{HTML}{FF8A80}

\begin{filecontents}{testdata.csv}
ALB,VAL,ERR,COR
AA,20.61,0.32,bblue
AA,20.88,0.55,bblue
AA,20.41,0.29,bblue
AAA,26.22,0.94,bblue
AAA,26.43,0.45,bblue
AAA,26.86,0.61,bblue
AAAA,29.91,0.76,bblue
AAAA,30.39,0.11,bblue
AAAA,30.11,0.49,bblue
AAAAA,34.71,0.43,rred
AAAAA,34.87,0.99,rred
AAAAA,34.81,0.26,rred
AAAAAA,40.33,0.64,rred
AAAAAA,40.18,0.03,rred
AAAAAA,40.4,0.83,rred
AAAAAAA,45.77,0.47,rred
AAAAAAA,45.93,0.95,rred
AAAAAAA,45.35,0.3,rred
AAAAAAAA,50.35,0.13,rred
AAAAAAAA,50.34,0.85,rred
AAAAAAAA,50.66,0.55,rred
\end{filecontents}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{testdata.csv}\datatable
\makeatletter
\pgfplotsset{
    /pgfplots/flexible yticklabels from table/.code n args={3}{%
        \pgfplotstableread[#3]{#1}\coordinate@table
        \pgfplotstablegetcolumn{#2}\of{\coordinate@table}\to\pgfplots@yticklabels
        \let\pgfplots@yticklabel=\pgfplots@user@ticklabel@list@y
    }
}
\makeatother
\begin{figure}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ylabel=A labels,  y label style={at={(-0.1,0.5)}}, 
    y = -0.3cm,
    ybar, %=2*\pgflinewidth,
    draw opacity=0.5,
    bar width=6pt,
    enlarge y limits={abs=7pt},
    xbar, 
    width=.36\textwidth,
    xlabel= unit,
    %flexible xticklabels from table={testdata.csv}{ALB}{col sep=comma}, 
    flexible yticklabels from table={testdata.csv}{ALB}{col sep=comma},
    yticklabel style={font=\small,xshift=0.5ex,  anchor=east},  
    %xtick=data
    ytick=data,
    xmajorgrids
]
%\pgfplotsinvokeforeach {0}{
    \addplot
    %style={color=cyan,fill=bblue,mark=none};
    plot [error bars/.cd, x dir=both,x explicit ] 
        table[y expr={(\coordindex) - mod(\coordindex,3)/8},x=VAL, x error=ERR ] {\datatable};

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{figure}
```

Comment: This definitely looks like a bug in pgf to me, `mod(18,3)` gives `3`, which is not expected.

Comment: @TonioElGringo Does it? I get `0.0` from `\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgf}
\begin{document}
\pgfmathparse{mod(18,3)}\pgfmathresult
\end{document}`

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Indeed it works with `pgfmathparse`, but something is broken in `pgfplots`, since `\plot {mod(18,3)};` in an axis environment gives incorrect results.

Comment: @TonioElGringo True. I posted a report at https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/bugs/187/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Update 21.10.17.) This problem was caused by a bug in the floating point library: https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/bugs/187/ It has been fixed by Christian Feuersänger, and when the next version of `pgf` or `pgfplots` is released the code should work properly without the workaround described below.

---

<s>It could be that the `18` is seen as `17.99999` or something, so the `mod` gives the wrong output.</s>

If you change to `mod(\coordindex+0.001,3)` the output is as expected.

Unrelated comments:

- you have both `ybar` and `xbar` in the `axis` options, the `ybar` can be removed.
- `\addplot plot[..` is mixing TikZ syntax (`\draw plot`) with `pgfplots` syntax, you want `\addplot +[..` I think.
- As shown, you don't really need the `flexible yticklabels` stuff, `yticklabels from table={\datatable}{ALB}` is good enough.

[image: partial output of code]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable,filecontents}

\begin{document}

\definecolor{bblue}{HTML}{82B1FF}
\definecolor{rred}{HTML}{FF8A80}

\begin{filecontents}{testdata.csv}
ALB,VAL,ERR,COR
AA,20.61,0.32,bblue
AA,20.88,0.55,bblue
AA,20.41,0.29,bblue
AAA,26.22,0.94,bblue
AAA,26.43,0.45,bblue
AAA,26.86,0.61,bblue
AAAA,29.91,0.76,bblue
AAAA,30.39,0.11,bblue
AAAA,30.11,0.49,bblue
AAAAA,34.71,0.43,rred
AAAAA,34.87,0.99,rred
AAAAA,34.81,0.26,rred
AAAAAA,40.33,0.64,rred
AAAAAA,40.18,0.03,rred
AAAAAA,40.4,0.83,rred
AAAAAAA,45.77,0.47,rred
AAAAAAA,45.93,0.95,rred
AAAAAAA,45.35,0.3,rred
AAAAAAAA,50.35,0.13,rred
AAAAAAAA,50.34,0.85,rred
AAAAAAAA,50.66,0.55,rred
\end{filecontents}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{testdata.csv}\datatable

\begin{figure}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ylabel=A labels,
    y label style={at={(-0.1,0.5)}}, 
    y = -0.3cm,
    xbar, %=2*\pgflinewidth,
    draw opacity=0.5,
    bar width=6pt,
    enlarge y limits={abs=7pt},
    width=.36\textwidth,
    xlabel= unit,
    yticklabels from table={\datatable}{ALB},
    yticklabel style={font=\small,xshift=0.5ex,  anchor=east},  
    ytick=data,
    xmajorgrids
]
%\pgfplotsinvokeforeach {0}{
    \addplot
    %style={color=cyan,fill=bblue,mark=none};
    +[error bars/.cd, x dir=both,x explicit] 
        table[y expr={(\coordindex) - mod(\coordindex+0.001,3)/8},x=VAL, x error=ERR ] {\datatable};

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Now PGFPlots v1.16 is released and as Torbjørn T. already mentioned in his edited answer, your MWE now directly gives the expected result.