# Spacing after every nth bar

Tags: pgfplots, bar-chart

I'm trying to create a chart with bars. The bars should have no separation in between besides after every nth bar.

So in other words the bars should be displayed in groups of n bars, with no separation inbetween. Inbetween groups there should be a separation.

The bars come from a single `\addplot` command.

MWE:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        \addplot coordinates {
            (1,5) (2,10) (3,13) (4,18) (5,21) (6,25) (7,30) (8,50) (9,70)
        };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: you can group them if you separate the data and plot them individually in n `\addplot` commands by adding `ybar` key to axis

Comment: What is `n`? As you are plotting particular points I assume it's a particular number, possibly different for different plots?

Comment: You could do something similar to the technique used in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/395239 If you're using `ybars` you want an `x expr` instead of `y expr` of course.